# Push Not Coming in Production

Tags: objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I am not getting push in production Mode . while it work fine in developer mode.Here is my code I am newer in iOS and i am first time implementation APN. Please help. I am stuck in lot of time.

```
 if (iOSversion >=8) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }


    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];

    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)tokenss
{
    NSUInteger rntypes;
            NSString *device=[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion];
    int ar=[device intValue];
            if (ar>=8) {
        rntypes = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];
    }
    NSString *deviceToken =[self stringWithDeviceToken:tokenss];
            NSLog(@"Device token: %@", deviceToken);
          callBackToken =deviceToken;
      }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"%@",errorString);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
```

Comment: Check with Production mode certificates in iOS and Production mode in server Side ..(Check if any where it could be Sandbox mode)

Answer (score 0):

***Such problems are due to current Provisioning Profile does not contain APNS information, as the Provisioning Profile is created BEFORE creating the APNS certificate.***

*Therefore, to solve the problem, create a new Provisioning Profile & select the Provisioning Profile in Xcode will clear the error.*

Also, when you add push, I believe you have updated the certificates in keychain too.